# split a PKCS12 into its certificate and private key bytes

Tags: x509certificate

I have been able to OpenSSL tools to extract the certificate and private key bytes from an existing PFX (PKCS12) file.

However, I wish to do this using .NET. I am able to use the X509Certificate classes to load a PFX file and extract the certificate bytes but, I do not know how to extract the private key. The certificate (exported as a PFX file) was created using a sha1RSA aignature algorithm.

I know RSA classes exist in .NET but I do not know how to use them together.

Any advice will help.

Thanks in advance.

Subbu

Comment: Have a look at http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer here: [extract private key bytes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258771/extract-private-key-bytes-in-c/6259440#6259440)

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes. This helps. Thank you. I did try out the PemWriter today but was passing on the AsymmetricKeyParameter class which the PemWriter did not convert even after I casted it.